# What's so controversial about AFTs (Abbreviated Function Templates)?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

Why is this feature seen so controversial? I saw that it was not merged into C++20 along with the rest of the Concepts TS. Searching through the web, I couldn't find reasonable arguments except the generic ones that can be applied to almost any new C++ feature.

What are people so afraid of? What pitfalls could be in there? After all, we already have generic lambdas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following program:

```
void foo(Name&& x) {
    static int counter = 0;
    ++counter;
    x.func<int>(); // #1
}

Name x = ...;
foo(x); // #2

template <typename T> void some_algorithm(T);
some_algorithm(foo); // #3
```

If `Name` is a type, there is exactly one static variable named `counter`, `foo` is a single function that takes an rvalue reference, the call in `#1` is fine (presuming such a member function exists), the call in `#2` is ill-formed because `x` is an lvalue, and the call in `#3` is well-formed because `foo` just decays to a function pointer.

If `Name` is a concept, there is one static variable per type instantiated (including different value categories), `foo` is a function template that can only be defined in a header, the call in `#1` is ill-formed because you need an extra `template` keyword, the call in `#2` is well-formed because we just deduce an lvalue reference parameter, and the call to `#3` is ill-formed because you can't pass in a function template like that - you need to wrap it in a lambda or something.

This stacks on each parameter:

```
void foo(Name&&, OtherName&&);
```

Either name could be a type or a concept without a marker.

All based on what category of thing `Name` is. That's... a lot of difference (mind you the above is also not a *complete* list of the differences, just the biggest ones I can immediately think of), and there is concern that it is too much without commensurate benefit.

See also [P0696](https://wg21.link/p0696).

---

Note that none of this applies with generic lambdas and `auto` because `auto` is a keyword, and so `void foo(auto&& x)` would clearly be a function template. It's a clear marker that avoids all of this ambiguity.

Also note that [P1141](https://wg21.link/p1141) proposes using that same syntactic marker for AFTs:

```
void f(Sortable auto& x);
```

Given that seemingly everyone who has loudly voiced one opinion or other on this topic is a coauthor of that paper, I'd give it a better than average chance of success.

Comment: After your example, it's much more clear now. Indeed, I didn't even think about the case of `void foo(Name&&, OtherName&&);`, where one could be a concept and the other an RV reference. Thanks.